# unable to get data after submitting asp.net form using curl

Tags: asp.net, curl

I am trying to submit a asp form using curl request
the form is available on

http://www.fikeandfike.com/propertytax/Grundy/Inquiry.aspx

this form can only be accessed by clicking "Parcel Enquiry"

http://www.fikeandfike.com/propertytax/Grundy/MainMenu.aspx?c=32

I have written a curl script to access the for and submit the form but the output is not coming as expected. 
Actually the post method is not doing anything.
I tried net modelling on firebug and found that a interim page redirects to the webpage on which data is displayed.
after executing the curl all I get is a blank screen.
is there any problem because of that interim page redirecting to final page after submit button is pressed. please help.